# Infopath 2007 - Emailed forms not rendering correctly

Tags: sharepoint, email, forms, rendering, infopath

So I have a form that uses infopath services via sharepoint, and after multiple attempts at attempting to fix a rendering problem (tables appear WAY too wide to be readable), I think I have found the problem : date controls.

It seems date controls within Infopath 2007 screw with rendering somehow.  To test, I made  2 variations of a VERY simple form - one with a date control, one with a text control - and placed them inside a table.

When emailed, the one with the date control rendered incorrectly.

My question is - has anyone experienced this before?  If you have time, test it out.  I think it is a bug or something, but not exactly sure.

I am using Infopath 2007, Sharepoint 2007, and Outlook 2007.

---

### **Updated Sept 19, 2008**

Yes, web form capability is checked.
Web compatible date controls?  I think so - everything looks perfect in the browser... only the email messes up.
and yes you are correct.  My mistake this is Sharepoint 2007.  I fixed it above.

If anyone has the time, try it out - it's very frustrating to have to use text boxes for dates.  Especially with the 'talent' we have here. lol

Comment: I just had the same problem.  I have had this problem in the past and making sure that the width of the controls is not 100% seems to have fixed the problem.  I have even had a form in the past with date pickers on it that worked fine, but not now.  My current form has 2 date pickers and both look whacked (long horizontally) when emailed.

Does anyone have updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have web form compatability checked in all the necessary places? Are you using the web compatible date controls? Are you sure you are using SharePoint 2003, I thought Form Services was a 2007 update.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the same issue I had(or maybe not)...InfoPath cache's the form on the client(seems to check for the form’s unique URN in the cache) which means that if you attempt to click on the email “Edit this task…” the new form is not downloaded, instead the InfoPath form from the cache is displayed.

Run the following on your cmd window to verify this...and post your findings here

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\INFOPATH.EXE" /cache clearall